# Problema de loop com $stateChangeStart

Tags: angularjs, ui-router

Olá pessoa estou criando um sistema de autenticação e verificação de niveis com Angularjs, estou usando o stateChangeStart para validar as permissões em view.

**Só que quando uso o $state.go('app.home'); ele entra em loop infinito.**

O meu código é o seguinte:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams)
   {      
      if (typeof(toState) !== undefined){
        $templateCache.remove(toState.templateUrl);
      }

      if($rootScope.session == undefined && $cookieStore.get('user') == undefined) 
      {
        $rootScope.session =  {};
      }else if($rootScope.session == undefined && $cookieStore.get('user') != undefined) 
      {   

          $rootScope.session = {
            set:true, 
            name : $cookieStore.get('user')['name'], 
            userid : $cookieStore.get('user')['id'], 
            role: $cookieStore.get('user')['nivel'],
            email: $cookieStore.get('user')['email']
          };          
      }

      if(toState.name === "page.login" || toState.name === "page.register")
      {
        return;
      }

      var authorized = true;

      if(Object.keys($rootScope.session).length === 0) 
      {
          event.preventDefault();
          $state.go('page.login');
          return;
      }else if(Object.keys(toState.permissions).length !== 0) {

        angular.forEach(toState.permissions, function(value, key)
        {
          angular.forEach(value, function(role) 
          {            
            if(key === 'except' && role === $rootScope.session.role)
            {
              authorized = false;
            }else if(key === 'allow' && role !== $rootScope.session.role)
            {
              authorized = false;
            }; 
          });  
        });
      }

      if(!authorized){
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('app.home');
        return;
      }; 

   }); // Start View
```

Tentei também:

```
var array = toState.permissions['except'];

if(array.indexOf($rootScope.session.role) > 0)
{
  authorized = false;
}
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Onde está o seu problema? É bom que você indique exatamente onde está o problema e qual o resultado desejado para que os usuários não tenham que ler seu código inteiro e adivinhar o que pode estar acontecendo de errado.

Comment: Foi mesmo, desculpe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, não existe nada realmente impedindo a continuação do código, ou seja, ele vai ler o seu código e independente de ter uma `session` ou não, o `var authorized` vai ser validado como `true` e ele vai passar.

Você precisa fazer sua verificação dentro de um mesmo bloco e garantir que o var authorized só seja validado como true se ele realmente estiver logado.

Outra observação, antes de fazer toda a verificação de `session`, verifique primeiro se o usuário está tentando acessar uma área restrita. Se for uma área pública, não há necessidade de verificar se o usuário está logado. Ou seja, a lógica da sua verificação deve ser algo mais ou menos assim:

> O state requer login? 
> se não -> continua 
> se sim -> verifica..
>
> O usuário está logado? 
> se sim -> continua 
> se não -> retorna para o login
>
> O usuário tem permissão? 
> se sim -> continua 
> se não -> retorna para página de permissão

Precisaria fazer alguns testes para identificar se realmente vai funcionar, mas acredito que a estrutura do seu código deva seguir algo +- assim:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
  if(toState.name === "page.login" || toState.name === "page.register") {
    return;
  } else {

    if (typeof(toState) !== undefined) {
      $templateCache.remove(toState.templateUrl);
    } else {

      if($rootScope.session == undefined && $cookieStore.get('user') == undefined) {
        $rootScope.session =  {};
        event.preventDefault();
        return $state.go('page.login');

      } else if($rootScope.session == undefined && $cookieStore.get('user') != undefined) {
        $rootScope.session = {
          set:true, 
          name : $cookieStore.get('user')['name'], 
          userid : $cookieStore.get('user')['id'], 
          role: $cookieStore.get('user')['nivel'],
          email: $cookieStore.get('user')['email']
        };

        var authorized = true;

        if(Object.keys(toState.permissions).length !== 0) {
          angular.forEach(toState.permissions, function(value, key) {
            angular.forEach(value, function(role) {            
              if(key === 'except' && role === $rootScope.session.role) {
                authorized = false;
              } else if(key === 'allow' && role !== $rootScope.session.role) {
                authorized = false;
              };
            });
          });
        }

        if(!authorized) {
          event.preventDefault();
          return $state.go('app.home');
        };
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Espero que isso ajude você a entender melhor como organizar as verificações.

Comment: Esqueci de colocar meu problema, desculpe correria. Seguinte. Meu problema é que na hora que colocou o $state.go('app.home'); ele entra em loop infinito. Usei o window location e foi de boa. parece que o $state executa $stateChangeStart toda vez que é chamado, gerando um loop infinito.

Comment: Mas a execução sempre acontece. Por isso recomendei o uso de verificar a necessidade de login antes de verificar se o usuário está realmente autenticado. Isso deve resolver seu problema.